# Retrieve soap attachment with talend

Tags: soap, attachment, talend

I've defiened a web service in talend and I try to get the soap attachment of the request to this service but I don't know how to do. The file is an XMl.
When I look the request I received in talend I've this :

```
<ser:createSharePointFileOperationRequest xmlns:ser="http://www.talend.org/service/">
     <relativeServerPath>/facturation</relativeServerPath>
     <listName>Facture</listName>
     <fileName>Structure.xml</fileName>
     <content><inc:Include xmlns:inc="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:Structure.xml"></inc:Include></content>
     <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
     <metadata Name="titre">TitreTest</metadata>
     <metadata Name="code">015</metadata> 
</ser:createSharePointFileOperationRequest>
```

Do you know if there is a way to get this file?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `tFileFetch` component after the soap call. You'll have to extract url field from the response and transmit it to the tFileFetch component.

You won't be able to directly retrieve the file from the soap call itself.